# Insert query showing an error in oracle10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I created a table in oracle10g using following query......

```
  CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEESTASKS" 
  ( "EMPLOYEEID" NUMBER, 
"TASKDATE" VARCHAR2(40), 
"STATUS" NUMBER, 
"CUSTOMERID" NUMBER, 
"ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"TASKTIME" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"VISITDATE" VARCHAR2(40), 
"VISITTIME" VARCHAR2(40), 
 CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEESTASKS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEEID", "TASKDATE", "TASKTIME") ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEESTASKS_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYEEID")
  REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEES" ("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
 )
```

Table was created successfully... but the problem is while iam trying to insert a row into the table it is showing the error

```
   ORA-01722: invalid number
```

The query i used is ,

```
 insert into employeestasks values(12305,'30-11-2011','09:00',0,45602,'Sarpavaram Junction ,kakinada',null,null)
```

What is that invalid number..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like your columns in the table are ordered employeeid, taskdate, status, and you're trying to insert '09:00' into status, which is a number. This is no good. You need to use the same order of columns or specify which value is for which column.

Also, you really like capslock, huh?